# ADF Copy Activity ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am getting the following error in ADF during a copy activity:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column 'contact_adres_begindatum' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'
```

I try to copy data from an API call that returns a response in json format and try to copy it to an Azure SQL database.

The problem that I encounter is when the json data contains some "null" values. The json data looks as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn9U1.png)

When I press on "Import schemas", I get the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQaqC.png)

As can be seen, this gives a "Null" value for the "contact_adres_begindatum".

Basically whenever there is a "null" value given in the json format of the API response, I want to set it as NULL in the SQL database.

I have googled everywhere but cannot find any solution to this problem. How could I solve this? Thanks for your help!

I tried googling, ChatGPT, Microsoft Forum but I could not find how to solve this problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

On the mapping tab of the copy activity, select the string data type for the `contact adres begindatum` column in the sink side, as shown below:

[image]

After doing this, the copy activity will debug successfully without any errors, and the data will be copied to the SQL database, as shown below:

[image]